# crash in using in app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

iam using this code on click on the item after init the buy process

```
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.skDollar_15] ;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment] ;
```

it works fine in the first time but if i out of the screen and comeback again and try to perform this code again the application crash in this line

```
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment] ;
```

Comment: Please show the stack trace and variables when it crashes.

Comment: its just like debugging , nothing on console its just the application stopped , error exec .. . , even i put this code in try ad catch , the fun thing that the code crashes in the try but stop there and don't go to catch

Comment: you should turn on all exception breakpoint in your breakpoint tab.

Comment: i removed all of them , while running the application stop at this line with this green select line like if you put a break point , but no break points there

Answer (score 0):

The document say:

> The payment request must have a product identifier registered with the
>   Apple App Store and a quantity greater than 0. If either property is
>   invalid, addPayment: throws an exception.

quantity is default to one, so check if your product identifier is valid not nil.